# Create a column per year defined within a timeframe range

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe with variables, 2 of which are the start and end year of the data collection timeframe.

i.e.

```
Var1  Var2   start   end
 1     A     2000   2022
 2     B     1990   1995
 3     C     2005   2006
...   ...     ...    ...
```

I would like to modify this dataframe so that a column for every year is displayed and the presence/absence of data for each year is coded as a binary variable (1/0).

Because the dataset has thousands of rows and many varied year ranges I would like this process to be automated and not manual.

i.e.

```
Var1  Var2   1990   1991  1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 ... 2021  2022
 1     A      0      0     0    0     0   0     0       1      1
 2     B      1      1     1    1     1   1     0       0      0     
 3     C      0      0     0    0     0   0     0       0      0
```

Then I would like to transform this dataframe so that the years are displayed into 1 row

i.e.

```
Year  Var1  Var2  Data_Availability
1990  1      A           0
1990  2      B           1
1990  3      C           0
...
2022  1      A           1
2022  2      B           0
2022  3      C           0
```

Any help on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit cumbersome but it is an option. The methodology is to convert to long so `start` and `end` are one column. Then group by the `Var2` and complete the sequence of year. Spread to wide to get the dummy variables then convert again to long to get the structure you want, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>% 
 pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) %>% 
 group_by(Var2) %>% 
 complete(value = seq(min(value), max(value))) %>% 
 select(1, 2) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = value) %>% 
 mutate_at(-1, ~ (ifelse(is.na(.), 0, 1))) %>% 
 pivot_longer(-1)

# A tibble: 87 x 3
# Groups:   Var2 [3]
#   Var2  name  value
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     2000      1
# 2 A     2001      1
# 3 A     2002      1
# 4 A     2003      1
# 5 A     2004      1
# 6 A     2005      1
# 7 A     2006      1
# 8 A     2007      1
# 9 A     2008      1
#10 A     2009      1
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to pivot longer, expanding with all years between 1990 and 2022, and identifying which rows are between start and end.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat_long <- dat |> 
        pivot_longer(start:end, values_to = "Year")

dat_long |> 
        full_join(data.frame(Var1 = 1, Var2 = "A", Year = 1990:2022)) |>
        expand(Var1, Var2, Year) |>
        left_join(dat_long) |> 
        group_by(Var1, Var2) |> 
        fill(name) |> 
        mutate(Data_Availability = case_when(name == "start" | name == "end" & lag(name == "start") ~ 1,
                                             TRUE ~ 0)) |> 
        select(Year, Var1, Var2, Data_Availability)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Vector of names of the start-end years:
# start_end_year_col_names => character vector 
start_end_year_col_names <- c("start", "end")

# Calculate the range of years in start end dates: 
# year_rng => integer vector
year_rng <- Reduce(
  seq, 
  range(
    unlist(
      df[,start_end_year_col_names]
    )
  )
)

# Compute whether or not start ends fall within range, 
# and column bind other variables: data.frame => stdout(console)
cbind(
    df[,names(df) != start_end_year_col_names],
    setNames(
      data.frame(
        t(
        vapply(
          seq_len(nrow(df)),
          FUN = function(i){
            +(df$start[i] <= year_rng & df$end[i] >= year_rng)
          },
          integer(length(year_rng))
        )
      )
    ),
    year_rng
  )
)
```

Data:

```
# df => data.frame

df <- structure(list(Var1 = 1:3, Var2 = c("A", "B", "C"), start = c(2000L, 
1990L, 2005L), end = c(2022L, 1995L, 2006L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Var1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
  Var2 = c("A", "B", "C"),
  start = c(2000L, 1990L, 2005L),
  end = c(2022L, 1995L, 2006L)
)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(period = map2(start, end, ~seq(.x, .y))) %>% 
  mutate(period_all = list(seq(1990, 2022))) %>% 
  mutate(res = map2(period_all, period, ~+(.x %in% .y))) %>% 
  mutate(res = map2(res, period_all, ~set_names(x = .x, nm = .y))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(res) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("period"))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 37
#>    Var1 Var2  start   end `1990` `1991` `1992` `1993` `1994` `1995` `1996`
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1     1 A      2000  2022      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 2     2 B      1990  1995      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
#> 3     3 C      2005  2006      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#> # … with 26 more variables: `1997` <int>, `1998` <int>, `1999` <int>,
#> #   `2000` <int>, `2001` <int>, `2002` <int>, `2003` <int>, `2004` <int>,
#> #   `2005` <int>, `2006` <int>, `2007` <int>, `2008` <int>, `2009` <int>,
#> #   `2010` <int>, `2011` <int>, `2012` <int>, `2013` <int>, `2014` <int>,
#> #   `2015` <int>, `2016` <int>, `2017` <int>, `2018` <int>, `2019` <int>,
#> #   `2020` <int>, `2021` <int>, `2022` <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You might do this in two lines of code using `seq` and `ifelse`.

```
oa_seq <- do.call(seq.int, as.list(range(unlist(df[3:4]))))
cbind(df[1:2], `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(Map(seq.int, df$start, df$end), \(x) ifelse(oa_seq %in% x, 1, 0))), oa_seq))
#   Var1 Var2 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
# 1    1    A    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# 2    2    B    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 3    3    C    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
#   2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022
# 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# 2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

*R >= 4.1 was used.*

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = 1:3, Var2 = c("A", "B", "C"), start = c(2000L, 
1990L, 2005L), end = c(2022L, 1995L, 2006L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```